Virtual network interface and route(s) to bypass VPN
I'm frequently connected to a system-wide VPN which I need to bypass for certain applications. On my home network I currently run a SOCKS proxy on another box which I use, for example, in a separate "no VPN" Firefox profile. What I need is a self-contained way to do this on any LAN, hopefully on an interface level but not necessarily.

How do I create such an interface, and have it use whichever "parent" connection is available (Ethernet, WiFi)? Is this TUN/TAP? Bridge?
Is there a way to apply the original (no VPN) default route I got from the router to this interface, allowing traffic to bypass the new default route from the VPN? I need this to "just work" on hotel WiFi, for example.

VirtualBox has a cool "bridged" network adapter that appears just like a separate physical device on the LAN with its own MAC/IP. Maybe there's a way to replicate that?
Looking for specific ip commands or NetworkManager instructions (running Debian KDE).

I'm not sure I really understand the purpose of a virtual interface – what would it achieve that the existing Wi-Fi interface does not? From your points 1 and 2, it sounds like you're asking for exactly the same functionality as you already have.

The existing wifi interface has an IP that falls under the default VPN route. I want some traffic to bypass the VPN. Maybe this can be achieved by assigning an additional IP to an existing interface, and creating a route for it?

That doesn't matter at all – the default route doesn't care about your own interface addresses. Is this an IPsec VPN with strongswan, or a more typical VPN with its own tap/tun interface? At least with the latter, there are already ways to achieve this with only routes, and introducing a new virtual interface would have zero effect on the process.

It's WireGuard with its own interface. Routes work for specific IPs/subnets, but I don't see how they will separate applications like an interface can. You can bind to it, create a network namespace, etc.

If you specifically want something that you could put in a network namespace, create a macvlan or ipvlan interface. Those are the closest built-in equivalent to the way VirtualBox's "bridged networking" network tap driver behaves – a macvlan will have its own MAC address and works as if it were bridged to its parent interface, whereas an ipvlan will share the original MAC address.
Macvlan interfaces do not support the MAC address masquerading that VirtualBox also does when it's attached to a Wi-Fi network (which are limited to one MAC per associated client), so ipvlan would be the more useful choice.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/getting-started-with-ipvlan_configuring-and-managing-networking

(Alternatively, you could create a veth-pair to act as a cable between the main namespace and the separate namespace; packets will follow the host's routing table, where you can use "policy routing" to direct everything coming from veth0 to use a specific table.)
For all other situations, this kind of virtual interface is not really useful because it only does exactly the same thing that your real interface also does – the original eth0 or wlan0 interface has not lost its access to the local network, so there's no need for a new one; and even if you did create a new ipvlan interface, the only way to actually use it would be to do basically the same process as you're already doing.
That is, even if the VPN is active, you can still tell software to bind sockets to wlan0, or to the IP address of wlan0, in the same way that you might with a virtual interface – either way it's the routing table, not the interface, that influences which default route will be used; and either way you'll need to mess around with "policy routing" to make it work, so you might as well do it directly with the real interface.

Yes, I was making this too complicated. It is possible to use the original interfaces directly, but software needs to bind specifically to wlan0 and NOT the IP address of wlan0 to bypass default routing. Also expect problems with DNS leaks. Thanks for macvlan/ipvlan, very cool!

One remaining challenge is making this work when switching from WiFi to Ethernet without needing to rebind to another interface. Any ideas?
